# OS X El Capitan - command line Operation not permitted although using sudo

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to create symbolic link using mac terminal command line but I am getting "Operation not permitted". See code below:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
Password:
ln: /usr/bin/drush: Operation not permitted
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe http://superuser.com is a better place to ask such questions.

Comment: I think you are falling foul of *System Integrity Protection* - check out osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac…

Answer (score 0):

Your user must be a member of the group admin, or edit the /etc/sudoers file to be able to use sudo. More information on "man sudoers".

Answer (score 0):

Commands you install separately from the OS belong in /usr/local, so you should put the link in /usr/local/bin, not /usr/bin. /usr/local/bin doesn't exist by default, but it's in the default PATH so if you create it, it will be automatically recognized:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
```

You could also set the permissions on /usr/local/bin to allow members of the admin group to install things there, so you can add the link without `sudo`:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
sudo chgrp admin /usr/local/bin    # Assign the directory to the "admin" group
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/bin    # Grant the group write access
ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush    # No `sudo` needed!
```

Note that putting custom/local stuff in /usr/local has been a standard convention for along time, but starting in El Capitan it's enforced by [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really). It's possible to disable SIP, but in most cases (like this one) it's better to follow the standard convention.